# How to enforce the use of HTTPS on Information Security

Tags: feature-request

Is there any option or preferences to enforce the use of HTTPS that is now available for Information Security (not the meta version yet) ?
I would found it useful instead of using an extension of my browser to force that behavior.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Google Chrome I know you can manually enforce HSTS on the domain. You can read [my blog on HSTS here](https://scotthelme.co.uk/hsts-the-missing-link-in-tls/) and then enforce HSTS in Google Chrome [with this blog here](https://scotthelme.co.uk/manually-enforcing-hsts-chrome/). You can set HSTS on the security.stackexchange.com domain without affecting the meta subdomain. This may not be the method you were looking for but it should achieve what you want.

Comment: well too bad I don't as I matter a bit for my personnal data :/

Comment: Sorry about that, it was worth mentioning though I suppose.